# Google spreadsheet onEdit execution time

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

i have a sheet in which the onEdit function is used to update a specific cell with the editor username.
This is the code:

```
function onEdit(e) {

  Logger.log('-> START');
  var row = e.range.getRow();
  var col = e.range.getColumn();

  //sheetConfig.getRange('G3').setValue(new Date());
  //sheetConfig.getRange('G4').setValue(currentUser);

  if(col == esitoColumn) {

    if(sheetCL.getRange(row, col).getValue() != '') {

      Logger.log('Post check valore cella editata');

      if(sheetCL.getRange(row, configDataColumn).getValue() == 'HOUR_LINE')
        massiveEdit(row);
      else {

        Logger.log('Post check valore cella di configurazione');
        sheetCL.getRange(row, userColumn).setValue(currentUser);
        Logger.log('Post set username');
      }
    }
    else
      sheetCL.getRange(row, userColumn).clearContent();
  }

  Logger.log('-> END');
}
```

These are a couple of executions (look at timestamps):

```
[18-07-16 18:11:23:363 CEST] -> START
[18-07-16 18:11:23:461 CEST] Post check valore cella editata
[18-07-16 18:11:23:462 CEST] Post check valore cella di configurazione
[18-07-16 18:11:23:464 CEST] Post set username
[18-07-16 18:11:23:464 CEST] -> END

[18-07-16 18:11:40:343 CEST] -> START
[18-07-16 18:11:40:437 CEST] Post check valore cella editata
[18-07-16 18:11:40:439 CEST] Post check valore cella di configurazione
[18-07-16 18:11:40:441 CEST] Post set username
[18-07-16 18:11:40:442 CEST] -> END
```

As you can see the total execution time needed by the function is around **100 milliseconds**.
The real amount of time needed to visualize the username in the proper cell is about 1.5 seconds (**15x** the function execution time).
What can i do to solve the problem?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: The function is executing on Google's servers, not your web browser. You can't make Google update the UI information in your web browser faster.

Comment: You need to factor in I/O costs: which is a minimum base of 1 to 5 seconds,regardless of your actual execution time.

Comment: So there isn't anything i can do to enhance it it seems :(

Comment: Delete unnecessary rows/columns in your ss.

Comment: Use your browser developer tools and your operative system performance meter to checkout where are the bottlenecks.